# Which program provides "lpquota" command?

Tags: linux, command-line, printing

At many universities, you can buy a printing contingent which allows you to print out a certain amount of pages. At the Linux terminals, students can check their current printing contingent by executing the `lpquota` command. This does not seem to be a built-in command, but I could not find information about any associated software either. Nevertheless, searching on Google I found out that several universities offer the `lpquota` command. Is there some kind of convention which implementations must conform to, or are all universities using the same software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found lpquota Perl script from http://perlwatch.net/perl-scripts/, this might be the one you're looking for. Also DK Tools have `printqd` daemon for enforcing print quotas on LPRng print systems. This is available in http://dktools.sourceforge.net/printqd.html, which doesn't appear to be related.